# how to close the current browser window completely before opening the browser using perl

Tags: windows, perl

Here @links array consists of various URLs. According to the below code, first www.google.com is opened in firefox. then while entering the forloop, firefox gets killed;the first URL in the @links array is opened. the second URL is getting opened in a new tab while entering the forloop for the second time and after that the browser is getting killed. But i need to first kill firefox everytime it enters the forloop and then the URL should be opened in a new browser window. kindly help.

```
system("start https://www.google.com");

for($i=0;$i<@links;$i++)
{
    system("taskkill /im firefox.exe");
    system("start $links[$i]");
}
```

Comment: Why you need this? You can query this URLs with LWP

Comment: @PSIAlt - perhaps a code sample would help likestolearn out.

Comment: i need to open a url in my browser and read its pagesource and them close it. i need to do it for many urls.

Answer (score 1):

Use [WWW::Mechanize::Firefox](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?WWW%3a%3aMechanize%3a%3aFirefox) instead.

[MozRepl::RemoteObject](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?MozRepl%3a%3aRemoteObject) provides even lower-level access.

Comment: that doesn't work..i tried reading the page source of my url..it says ERROR GETing "urlname": Not Found. But i am able to open that url manually in the browser. That's why i am trying to open it in the browser, read the page source from there and then closing the browser before opening it for the next time. I have a lot of URLs in the array. So closing the browser every time after reading the pagesource would be ideal for me.

Comment: WWW::Mechanize::Firefox does open the URL in the browser. The browser window is simply hidden (by default?).

Comment: for($i=0;$i<$#links;$i++)
{
open $file1, ">>test.txt";
my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new();
$mech->agent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; ru; rv:1.9.2.18) Gecko/20110614 Firefox/3.6.18" );
my $psurl =$links[$i]; 
$mech->get($psurl);
print $file1 $mech->content();
} #This is not working

Comment: WWW::Mechanize != WWW::Mechanize::Firefox

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this :

```
system("start https://www.google.com");

foreach my $link (@links) {
    system("taskkill /im firefox.exe");
    system("start $link");
}
```

This is wrong :

```
for($i=0;$i<@links;$i++)
```

If you want to *iterate* like this, use :

```
for ($i=0; $i<$#links; $i++)
```

Comment: thanx for your response :) i tried doing this my @links=("https://www.youtube.com","https://www.facebook.com","https://www.yahoo.com");
but still didnt work as expected..

system("start https://www.google.com");

foreach my $link (@links) {
    system("taskkill /im firefox.exe");
    system("start $link");
}

Comment: Huh? `for($i=0;$i<$#links;$i++)` will skip the last element of `@links`. The OP had it right, or you could say `<=$#links`.

Comment: i am not able to post answer to let you know the exact problem. my @links consists of 3 elements. youtube.com, facebook.com and yahoo.com..for me facebook.com and yahoo.com are opening in the same window in different tabs

Answer (score 0):

`taskkill` sends a signal to one or more processes and returns immediately. It may take a few milliseconds for the signalled process to actually shut down, so give your process some time to respond to the kill signal:

```
system("taskkill /im firefox.exe");
sleep 1;
system("start $links[$i]");
```

Comment: my @links consists of 3 elements. youtube.com, facebook.com and yahoo.com..for me facebook.com and yahoo.com are opening in the same window in different tabs